# problems with a simple game

Tags: c

I am almost new to C programming and I wanted to develop a simple game where the player has to move the character on a line at the bottom of the screen, while enemies are randomly generated on the top line and every second existing enemies slide down of one line. I have 2 main questions: how can i make a function do something after a certain period of time (slide down the enemies of one line) and how can i make the character move as the player press the correspondent key WHILE the other function is working in cycle?

Comment: `Threads`  is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

One basic concept in games development is the separation of move and draw. Each enemy should have a "move" function and each enemy should have a "draw" function.

The "move" function should move the enemy one step... By this I mean the function just adds 1 to the y coordinate if its wants the enemy to move down, -1 if it wants it to move up, etc... It does NOT move the enemy across the screen in one go.

The "draw" function will take the position of the enemy and simply draw the enemy at that position, nothing more.

Once you have these two concepts you need the main game loop. The main game loop will loop through *all* the enemies and call the "move" function on each of them. It handles timing of frame rates but skip this for simplicity... afterwards it will loop through the enemies and call the "draw" functions.

Once you have this set up, all you need to do once per main game loop is handle your key presses and move heroX, heroY accordingly.

Play with this concept and you will find it very powerful. It becomes easy to add and remove enemies, collision detection becomes simpler, etc. Good luck.